# android 6.0.1 immersive sticky not working

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-immersive

using the code below in my activity:

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            View decorView = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide
                    // nav
                    // bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
```

I was able to hide and swipe to show the system UI (and auto hide by it self after a few seconds) as described in android developer site using android device 5.0 and 7.0 but cannot on 6.0.1 android device. Are there any other way to use immersive sticky on android 6.0.1, I just want to hide the system UI and just let the user swipe to show the system UI (and auto hide if no interaction after a few second)